# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'coords'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, astropy

I have a problem compiling this in python3, the code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord 
from astropy.coordinates import ICRS, Galactic, FK4, FK5  
from astropy.coordinates import Angle, Latitude, Longitude  
import astropy.units as u


filename = get_pkg_data_filename('jopi.fits')


hdu = fits.open(filename)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header).celestial
wcs.wcs.crval = [0,0]
wcs.wcs.ctype = [ 'XOFFSET' , 'YOFFSET' ]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data[0][0], origin='lower') 
lon = ax.coords[0]
lat = ax.coords[1]
lon.set_major_formatter('x')
lat.set_major_formatter('x')
lon.set_format_unit(u.milliarcsecond)
lat.set_format_unit(u.milliarcsecond)
ax.set_xlim(200,800)
ax.set_ylim(200,800)
ax.set_xlabel('Relative R.A ()')
ax.set_ylabel('Relative Dec ()')
```

I always get

> lon = ax.coords[0] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'coords'

Is it something missing?

Comment: Does using `ax.imshow` instead of `plt.imshow` help instead?

Comment: ax.imshow? not at all

Answer (score 1):

This means that the `ax` variable has the value of `None`.  It is not an `Axes` object as you are expecting.  You could confirm this with some basic debugging e.g. putting a print statement after:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=wcs)
```

though I would also recommend looking at the code for `fig.add_subplot`.  In IPython/Jupyter you can type `fig.add_subplot??` to see this, and the first lines of the code for the function (after the docstring) are:

```
        if not len(args):
            return
```

(which IMO is a confusing misfeature).

You need to pass some additional arguments to `fig.add_subplot` as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot).

For example:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
```

to give the layout and position of the subplot you want to work on.

You are likely using matplotlib < 3.1.0, since this was changed in matplotlib 3.1.0 so that `Figure.add_subplot` has a default value of `111` for the position arguments, allowing code like you wrote to work:  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13127

Comment: I have tried before. In fact, I found out the problem relies on the python version. After installing the last python version, it works ok now.

Comment: It's not the Python version. It's the matplotlib version, like I wrote. On matplotlib < 3.1 you had to explicitly provide an argument to add_subplot. If you are trying a different Python version it may have worked because at the same time you installed a newer version of matplotlib.